# Can't correctly make refresh_token to get new token after it expires in youtube api v3

Tags: youtube-api, google-oauth

I want to do some stuff with the youtube api. For instance, to get my playlists, I use this url:

[playlist.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list)

```
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=($type)&mine=true&key=($api_key)
```

Using a `get` method with this header:

```
Authorization: Bearer ($token)
Accept: application/json'
```

Where `part` can be `id`, `snippet` and other I don't remember now.
I got the api key in the developers console. Then I created Oauth2 credentials. And the `token` is obtained from (directly in a browser):

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=($client)&redirect_uri=($uri)&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube&response_type=token&approval_prompt=force
```

Where the `redirect_uri` is established when creating the oauth2 credentials and `client_id` is part of those credentials.

And this works, I can use the youtube api to do the things I need.

But, the token expires after 1 hour aprox. So I have to get the token again every time:(

Searching around, I found out that there is a `refresh_token` that you can use to ask for a new `token`.

As far as I could get from the web, this `refresh_token` is obtained via this url:

```
echo $"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=($client)&redirect_uri=($uri)&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube&response_type=code&access_type=offline&prompt=consent"
```

Then, to request a new `token` (or to refresh it), I need to `post` on this url:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=($client)&redirect_uri=($uri)&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube&response_type=code&access_type=offline&prompt=consent
```

With `content type: application/json`.

I've tried several bodies (`client_secret` is part of the oauth2 credentials):

```
"client_id": ($client),
"client_secret": ($secret),
"refresh_token": ($refresh_token),
"grant_type": "authorization_code",
"access_type": "offline",
"prompt": "consent",
"scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"
```

That one gives me this error:

```
╭───────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────╮
│ error             │ invalid_request                  │
│ error_description │ Missing required parameter: code │
╰───────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────╯
```

Using `grant_type = code`, gives me:

```
╭───────────────────┬──────────────────────────╮
│ error             │ unsupported_grant_type   │
│ error_description │ Invalid grant_type: code │
╰───────────────────┴──────────────────────────╯
```

So, any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The corect call to use the refresh token to get a new access token is

```
HTTP POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=1/ffYmfI0sjR54Ft9oupubLzrJhD1hZS5tWQcyAvNECCA&grant_type=refresh_token
```

This is a http Post call, and the body should be sent as html query string format. NOT JSON.

Your issue is with the grant_type it needs to be refresh_token

useful links

- [Google 3 Legged OAuth2 Flow](https://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/)
- [Understanding Google OAuth 2.0 with curl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBC_tVJIx5w)